# Android Studio: Install flutter plugin error

Tags: android-studio, flutter-plugin

I try to install Flutter plugin in Android Studio. The plugin was installed but I don't see Flutter in `Settings -> Language & Framework.` When I create new Flutter project IDE throw an error. I'm not allow  to post image so please check the image url below.

[image: Flutter was installed]

[image: Not seen in Settings -> Language & Framework]

[image: Error when try to create new Flutter project]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Android Studio in a new folder, not in same folder as before. Instead of `C://Program Files/Android/Android Studio`, in something like `C://Program Files/Android/Andrew_Studio` and install the Flutter plugin again, maybe it will help.